# Cordova/Phonegap-facebook-plugin Android: facebookConnectPlugin is not defined

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

For Android, I keep getting this error, for this 
    phonegap-facebook-plugin 
https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/issues/758

```
ReferenceError: facebookConnectPlugin is not defined
```

I've tried removing all platforms, removing all platforms, and adding just this plugin.

I currently have only these only plugins installed:
    RoverMR:ionic_git_android rover$ cordova plugin
    com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin 2.3.1 "PushPlugin"
    com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect 0.8.1 "Facebook Connect"
    org.apache.cordova.device 0.2.12 "Device"
RoverMR:ionic_git_android rover$

In my config.xml:

```
<feature name="org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.facebook.ConnectPlugin" />
</feature>
```

My setup:

RoverMR:ionic_git_android rover$ npm --version
1.4.28
RoverMR:ionic_git_android rover$ cordova -v
4.0.0
RoverMR:ionic_git_android rover$ ionic -v
1.2.8

Any ideas?

Any ideas about the Android issue? What other info should I post to resolve this?For Android, I keep getting this:

```
ReferenceError: facebookConnectPlugin is not defined
```

I've tried removing all platforms, removing all platforms, and adding just this plugin.

I currently have only these only plugins installed:
    RoverMR:ionic_git_android rover$ cordova plugin
    com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin 2.3.1 "PushPlugin"
    com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect 0.8.1 "Facebook Connect"
    org.apache.cordova.device 0.2.12 "Device"
RoverMR:ionic_git_android rover$

In my config.xml:

```
<feature name="org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.facebook.ConnectPlugin" />
</feature>
```

My setup:

RoverMR:ionic_git_android rover$ npm --version
1.4.28
RoverMR:ionic_git_android rover$ cordova -v
4.0.0
RoverMR:ionic_git_android rover$ ionic -v
1.2.8

Any ideas?

Any ideas about the Android issue? What other info should I post to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOVLED! Problem was missing KEY HASH in Facebook App (see developer.facebook.com dashboard, android)

To add a key hash, run keytool (in the SDK you're using the build/run the app)

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

password default seems to be "android"

All other bad passwords will give you the same bad key.

Only the correct password will generate a different, good key.

Put this key into FB.

In Native dev, this error is much more visible. You get a FB error or can see key hash mentioned in error console logs. It'd be nice if this plugin could do the same.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem; in my case the issue turned out to be that I was using the PhoneGap Developer App which, apparently, doesn't support custom plugins at all.