# Cordova Facebook login

Tags: facebook, cordova, authentication, build

I installed the plugin as mentioned in the [docs](http://www.phonegaptutorial.com/integrate-facebook-into-your-phonegap-app/)
I cant find a way to get it working.
When I run the apk on android I get this:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: facebookConnectPlugin is not defined(…)

Here are me files.

*index.html*

```
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

*index.js*

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
// Bind Event Listeners
//
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
},
// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    //FB login
    facebookConnectPlugin.login(
        ["public_profile"],
        fbLoginSuccess,
        function (error) { alert("" + error) }
    );

    var fbLoginSuccess = function (userData) {
        alert("UserInfo: " + JSON.stringify(userData));
    }


}
};

app.initialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've had issues with using the FB plugin in my app development too. Sometimes it's necessary to include the FacebookConnectPlugin.js file in your index.html, as well as include this script, which injects the Facebook Javascript SDK into your app.

Source: https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/issues/446

Other threads about the same issue:

- [Cordova/Phonegap-facebook-plugin Android: facebookConnectPlugin is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548555/cordova-phonegap-facebook-plugin-android-facebookconnectplugin-is-not-defined)
- [facebookConnectPlugin is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29892779/facebookconnectplugin-is-not-defined)
- [facebookConnectPlugin is not defined (ngCordova, Ionic app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27906239/facebookconnectplugin-is-not-defined-ngcordova-ionic-app)
- ...

Comment: Thanks for the reply , but this doesnt solve my issue.facebookConnectPlugin is still undefined

Comment: did you check out ALL stackoverflow threads about that error? there are a lot more, you can find them with google by just entering that error message. what exactly did you try? please add that to your question.